# Azure PostgreSQL connection string with SSL MODE as prefer or VerifyFull

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl

We are connecting our .NET Web API application hosted on Azure App Services to PostgreSQL using Managed Identity.

The query is on SSL MODE used in connection string we use:

```
Server=xxxxx.postgres.database.azure.com;User id=xxxx;Database=xxx;port=5432;Ssl Mode=**Prefer**;Password="
```

vs

```
Server=xxxxx.postgres.database.azure.com;User id=xxxx;Database=xxx;port=5432;Ssl Mode=**VerifyFull**;Password="
```

What difference does it do if connectivity is from Azure App Services to Azure PostgreSQL instance?

As per:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html

prefer= I don't care about encryption, but I wish to pay the overhead of encryption if the server supports it.

VerifyFull=I want my data encrypted, and I accept the overhead. I want to be sure that I connect to a server I trust, and that it's the one I specify.

We were getting error of
System Exception: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxxx, user "xxxx", database "xxxx", no encryption
but somehow the error stopped when we used SSL Mode to VerifyFull.

searching all documentations

Answer (score 0):

> What difference does it do if connectivity is from Azure App Services to Azure PostgreSQL instance?

Azure Database for PostgreSQL automatically enables SSL connections between your server and client applications by default. This security measure helps safeguard against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks, ensuring a high level of protection for your server connections.

While it is not advisable, you do have the choice to disable the requirement for SSL when connecting to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL server if your client application does not support SSL connectivity. For detailed instructions on configuring SSL connectivity for your Postgres server in Azure, please refer to the documentation. You can [disable the requirement for SSL connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security) either through the Azure portal or using the command-line interface (CLI). It's important to note that Azure discourages disabling the requirement for SSL connections when connecting to your server.